# How do I make all .c file types open in the internal editor in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, editor

I have installed CDT plugin into Eclipse for file types associated with .c extension and follow the steps as [mentioned here for the file association.](https://superuser.com/questions/112410/how-do-i-make-all-file-types-open-in-the-internal-editor-in-eclipse) But still when I am trying to open any .c file Windows is asking me to select the editor. [image]

Comment: What is listed into _Associated editors_ for `*.c` files?

Comment: You say 'Windows' is asking you to select an editor - the Eclipse file associations only work inside Eclipse.

Comment: we are migrating one application from c to java so we want to see the c codes and we are working on Eclipse IDE,

Comment: Hi  greg ('Windows' is asking you to select an editor) Why I mention this because I am getting this pop up from Windows and Eclipse was unable to associate the .C files with c/c++ Editor